# Help with Getting out of grub rescue: unknown filesystem after Deleting Linux Partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grubrescue

I am on a laptop with dual-boot Windows 10/Ubuntu. I recently attempted to remove the Linux partition (It didn't play nicely with my laptop), and got myself stuck in the GRUB Rescue. I do not have access to my Windows disc (it's broken), and the road is full of snow. The only other computer in the house is a MacBook Pro 2011 edition. I have all files needed for a Windows install, but they're in the Windows partition. Trying ls returned (hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1), but none of these work. Is there anything I can do to simply boot into Windows just once?
I repeat, I DO NOT have access to my Windows install CD.

Comment: scroll down a bit to find the answers explaining what to do if you don't have a Windows disc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since creating a Windows 10 installation USB from a non-Windows computer can be quite troublesome that I know of, one method is to use the Mac to create an Ubuntu installation USB and reinstall Ubuntu, which will enable you to boot to Windows via grub. You can also access your Windows files from the Ubuntu live session if you think it will be helpful.

Comment: Installing `lilo` should be enough to boot Windows.

Comment: I think it's the simplest approach, although not the cleanest. I've no experience with lilo, so I can't comment.

Comment: It's not terribly difficult to create a Windows 10 installation USB on Ubuntu. See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/487970/301745).

Answer (score 0):

If you can make an Windows installer DVD or USB then boot to it, go to repair, then go to CMD and type: bootrec /fixmbr. Otherwise wait till you have a nice friend to let you borrow one.

Comment: It is possible to do it without a Windows DVD. This scenario is described in the duplicate question.

Comment: If you have a Mac then there will be guides on Google on how to make an bootable USB. If he has an Ubuntu installation then he can do startup disk